# Shopify buy button add only one quantity to cart

Tags: shopify, cart

I have implemented 'Shpoify Buy Button' in Symfony Project. I want restrict add more quantity to cart.

Below is my json code of 'Shpoify Buy Button':

```
Shopify.render('shopify-btn', {{ current_program.shopifyId|json_encode|raw }}, {
                "product": {
                    "buttonDestination": "checkout",
                    "variantId": "all",
                    "contents": {
                        "img": false,
                        "imgWithCarousel": false,
                        "title": false,
                        "variantTitle": false,
                        "price": false,
                        "description": false,
                        "buttonWithQuantity": false,
                        "quantity": false
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "button": "BUY NOW"
                    },
                    "styles": {
                        "product": {
                            "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                                "max-width": "100%",
                                "margin-left": "0",
                                "margin-bottom": "50px"
                            }
                        },
                        "button": {
                            "background-color": "#3771c8",
                            "font-size": "18px",
                            "font-weight": "bold",
                            "height": "61px",
                            ":hover": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            },
                            ":focus": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            }
                        },
                        "title": {
                            "font-size": "26px"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "font-size": "18px"
                        },
                        "compareAt": {
                            "font-size": "15px"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "cart": {
                    "contents": {
                        "button": false,
                        "quantity": false
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "total": "Total"
                    },
                    "popup":false,
                    "styles": {
                        "button": {
                            "background-color": "#3771c8",
                            ":hover": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            },
                            ":focus": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            }
                        },
                        "footer": {
                            "background-color": "#ffffff"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "modalProduct": {
                    "contents": {
                        "img": false,
                        "imgWithCarousel": true,
                        "variantTitle": false,
                        "buttonWithQuantity": false,
                        "quantity": false
                    },
                    "styles": {
                        "product": {
                            "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                                "max-width": "100%",
                                "margin-left": "0px",
                                "margin-bottom": "0px"
                            }
                        },
                        "button": {
                            "background-color": "#3771c8",
                            "font-size": "15px",
                            ":hover": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            },
                            ":focus": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "toggle": {
                    "styles": {
                        "toggle": {
                            "background-color": "#3771c8",
                            ":hover": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            },
                            ":focus": {
                                "background-color": "#3266b4"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "productSet": {
                    "styles": {
                        "products": {
                            "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                                "margin-left": "-20px"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

By using above json I can add / edit product quantity in cart.

I need to add only one quantity in cart also don't want add quantity by every click of "Shopify Buy Button" so how I can do that? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't have an answer but you may want to remove the unrelated items from that object. It will make it easier for people to see which options actually need modifying.